# Latest kernel update (.43) crashes my pae system

Tags: kernel, updates, pae

I have been happily running a 14.04 system but the latest kernel update has frozen my system. The background; I have been using the 32 bit ubuntu distribution (I have no idea why) and booting with the pae kernel to use the 12gb of ram I have available. I've been used to editing grub after each kernel update to ensure that it would boot using the pae version (using a normal, non-pae version just immediately crashes).

The latest update to the kernel 3.13.0-43 went through and I booted, without thinking, directly into it rather than interrupting the boot and selecting the pae version. It then booted as far as the login screen (with some graphical issues) which is farther than I typically got on non-pae kernels but then hung following login.

On reboot, even the pae version won't boot past login. So, I'm stuck. I'm running a live USB to try to recover files (which are backed up elsewhere as well...) and to post this problem.

Apologies in advance for the near complete lack of knowledge on my part, I'll do my best but probably best to give me instructions as though I was a four year old.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and did the following:

1. Boot in recovery mode, kernel 3.13.0-40
2. sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install fglrx (I'm using AMD graphics, so you might not have to do this)

and then I was able to boot again (now in .43) :)

Hope this works for you